# Wrong linkin when import index.ts file without specifying the file extension, when another index.vue file is in the same folder, using vue 3 and vite?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm, vite

How to import index.ts file without specifying the file extension, when another index.vue file is in the same folder, using vue 3 and vite?

I'm trying to import component:

```
import { Component } from '@/app/some_component'
```

```
src
|
└───
    app
    │   
    └───some_component
         │   index.ts
         │   index.vue
         │   ...
```

But Webstorm is refers to a index.vue by default.

So, how to make webstorm import **index.ts** file by default?

**P.S.** By the way, when i build application everything is ok, it seems to be the Webstorm's linking problem.

Here is the content of  **vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), tsconfigPaths()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 5000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8000
  },
  resolve: {
    alias:
      {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "@/app/styles/vars.scss";
        @import "@/app/styles/mixins.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Here is the content of **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: can you show us your vite config and tsconfig file ?

Comment: Updated with vite.config.ts and tsconfig.json content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the files without specifying the extensions, thanks to Vite. However, as you mentioned both of your files have the same names under the same folder, so you might face confusion while importing any of them. **The good idea is to use different names for the files and import them with that respected names.**

However, if there is any specific requirement to use the same name of Vue and TS files then one way would be to use [Vite's path aliasing feature](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/path-aliases). What you need to do is-

In your `vite.config.ts` file define the path alias for these files-

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'IndexTs': 'Path to index.ts file',
    'IndexVue': 'Path to index.vue file
  }
},
```

Inside your `tsconfig.json`, modify the `compilerOptions` section to include the paths mapping for your alias-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "paths": {
      ...,
      "@indexTs": ["Path to index.ts file"],
      "@indexVue": ["Path to index.vue file"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can easily import those files like that-

```
import something from '@indexTs';
import IndexVueComponent from '@IndexVue'
```